# security when Django 1.11, apache2 and mod_wsgi is used

Tags: django, security, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have read a few interesting [articles](https://www.adamerispaha.com/2016/12/14/file-permissions-for-django-media-uploads/) and watched a few [videos](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-au-2010/pyconau-2010--getting-started-with-apache-mod-wsg.html) but I'm afraid I still have a few things I need help with understanding. I'm a very new dabbler to all this.

1) The example listed in the blog made sense and I tried to implement it  but unfortunately my django project is in the home folder and the full wsgi path is /home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py. And since www-date needs read and execute permission in order to the open the folders leading up to the last mysite directory, I tried creating a new group which has rwx permission on the static and media folders.  This was ok for  the static and media folder because I used django collectstatic to move those files into the /var/www folder, which is also  has the group that www-data belongs as it's group.  The blog did not speak much about situations like mine; where  I have wsgi.py in my home folder as shown above.  So I tried to make the group of the home folder the same group that www-data belongs(recursively) but the end result was that I could not open the folder from the ubuntu's (GUI) interface even though I also put my username into the same group that is used by www-data and I confirmed that I was also  the owner of the directory when I did ls -l.  So I abandoned this method and I put www-data in the same group that my userid(the username that was used to build the server) belongs and  applied a chmod of 770 to the home folder recursively.  With  this change, apache was able to open my django app but I really think I may have created a security problem?

2)  In the video link, Graham Dumpleton, advised to apply a chmod of 0+rx to the wsgi path which in my case is (/home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/mysite/).  I suspect that means that any web user will now be able to read the files on the computer because Gramham also said people should consider moving django project to a none home location. In this forum,  I have seen people moving their project to /var/wwww and I have seen people comment that this is a risk. Gramham also spoke about moving wsgi file ONLY to a new location but I got lost during the explanation.

I suppose my questions are :
a) when a user is browsing a site, what permissions are they using; is it www-data or other  (o)? and when we say o+rx  are we giving these web users this permission through this command?. Is this enough permission for them to read the raw python code?

b) given my current situation, what's the simplest and effective way forward for me

Thanks forum.

Comment: Best is simply not place it under home directory. Alternately, have the ``wsgi.py`` outside of home directory under a directory under ``/var/www``. Then ensure using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and set ``user/group`` options of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` to be that for the owner/group of the home directory. Don't muck around with making anything in your home directory owned by Apache user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that

Comment: Graham, using your guide, I managed to get that working  and  www-data has zero permissions to my home folder path . I used the user variable in the mod_wsgi script as advised. So the ubuntu basically machine basically  does not need the password.. It just runs it as that username? Also, when a user accesses a we page to they access as 'other', what user do they use? What if I want the users to be able to upload photos . What kind of safe permissions should should I try to use?

Comment: Because you have set ``user`` option to your user, any code for your applications run as you. So uploads can only go to directories that you have write access to. Having stuff run as you is not great either, which is why you shouldn't stick code under home directories. Have the code under a subdirectory of ``/var/www`` and go back to running stuff as Apache user.

Comment: Thanks Graham,  I moved the wsgi.py file to a folder in /var/www.  Are saying that I should move the entire Django project out of the home directory as well? So far I have static  and media folders in /var/www. I also have the wsgi.py file in /var/www too. If I move the entire code to /var/www, am I  not exposing the code that way? I've never done it before so I'll have to find out how. My let me if I have to move the entire code or just the wsgi

Comment: If someone can find a vulnerability in your application code and is able to inject Python code to run somehow, they are going to be able to read stuff under your home directory since you are having to run the daemon process as you. If you have it all under ``/var/www`` running as Apache user, that is better because the Apache user can't read stuff under your home directory. So having stuff under home directory is worse if that means needing to run the daemon as you.

Comment: Graham forgive my ignorance.  The only thing I want to hide is the code, so  if I move it to /var/www will the hacker not have the same level of access to the entire Django code since www-data would have access to it too? The methodology for  protecting servers seems complex and not easy to understand. Could you please spare some time to enlighten me please or direct me to some of your old articles on this so I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, even under ``/var/www`` they would be able to get to the code. You can't avoid that as Python needs to be able to read the code to run it. What they wouldn't be able to get to is any other sensitive files you may have under your home directory, such as private SSH keys under ``~/.ssh``. So it isn't access to the source code you need to worry about, it is other stuff. Access to the source code you cannot stop if they break in through your application and can run code or commands.

Comment: I understand now. Thank  you so much for your patience .  I'll research and try this.